# Difference between Numpy and Matlab in multiplication of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy, complex-numbers

I am rewriting a program from Matlab to Python.
I realised a difference in a multiplication between arrays. Here is an example:

```
 A   = [-1822.87977846-4375.93518777j 
        3675.88618351+3824.34290883j
        971.68964707-2393.36758923j]
```

In Matlab:

```
A*A'= 5.7282e+07
```

In Python:

```
np.dot(A,A) = -21723405.178+39418085.0343j
```

How to obtain the same result of A'*A in Numpy?

Thank you.

Comment: You see the **`** in the Matlab-code? Yeah, it's important and not reflected within your python-code :-). Hint: **complex conjugate transpose operator**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all remember, in MATLAB, `'` is different than `.'`.

`'` does [complex conjugate transpose](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html)

`.'` does [non-conjugate transpose](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html)

On a real value vector or matrix both operators obtain similar result. However, on complex vectors or matrices they obtain different results. Check the links to find matlab examples for both.

In MATLAB, you can do the following:

```
A.'*A

ans =

     -2.172340517799748e+07 + 3.941808503424492e+07i
```

Comment: Few people know the difference between `.'` and `'` in Matlab. Most would just use `'`. Well done +1

Comment: Thank you, very useful reply. Do you know how  to obtain the A'*A operation in Numpy?

Comment: check the answer by @hpaulj

Answer (score 2):

On the Python side

```
In [488]: A=np.array( [-1822.87977846-4375.93518777j ,
     ...:         3675.88618351+3824.34290883j,
     ...:         971.68964707-2393.36758923j])
In [489]: A
Out[489]: 
array([-1822.87977846-4375.93518777j,  3675.88618351+3824.34290883j,
         971.68964707-2393.36758923j])
In [490]: A.conj()
Out[490]: 
array([-1822.87977846+4375.93518777j,  3675.88618351-3824.34290883j,
         971.68964707+2393.36758923j])
In [491]: A.dot(A.conj())
Out[491]: (57281826.560119703+0j)
In [492]: A.dot(A)
Out[492]: (-21723405.177997477+39418085.034244925j)
In [497]: np.vdot(A,A)
Out[497]: (57281826.560119703+0j)
```

In Octave, as pointed out in the other answer

```
>> A'*A
ans =    5.7282e+07
>> A.'*A
ans = -2.1723e+07 + 3.9418e+07i
>>
```

Comment: Thank you, indeed I would like to obtain the A'*A operation in Numpy!

Comment: Add a `.real` to my answers to remove the `0j` part.

Comment: plus-one For the Python side answer! :)  +1

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the `A*A'` Matlab operation in Numpy, you can do:

```
np.dot(A,np.conj(A))
```

Thank you!